# How to solve optimization problem using Gurobi

Tags: mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, gurobi

I am new in Gurobi. I wrote the following code. I save in Sample.lp. 
Run as

> gurobi_cl sample.lp

```
Maximize
 x1 +  x2 +  x3 + 1 x4 + 1 x5

Subject To
c1: 3 x1 + 5 x2 + 2 x3 + 5 x4 + 7 x5 - 28 <= 0
c2: 2 x1 + 0 x2 + 0 x3 + 8 x4 - 14 <= 0
c3: 4 x4 + 5 x5 - 22 <= 0
c4: 3 x2 - 2 <= 0
D1: 3 x4 -1 >= 0

Bounds
x1 <= 1
x2 <= 1
x3 <= 1
x4 <= 1
x5 <= 1

Integers
x1 x2 x3 x4 x5
End
```

It seems I am not getting correct solution. Can you please help me. 
Values of x are binary.

After modification, I am getting correct solution. If there is no objective function, my interest is to get a common binary solution. 
If there are many such solutions, I want to get few of them (say 1000).
How to tackle this?  For this if write

```
 Maximize
  1
```

I am getting error:

```
Solution count 0

Model is infeasible or unbounded
Best objective -, best bound -, gap -
```

Comment: I no nothing about gurobi but I see sometimes you use `*` as mulitplication and sometime you use space i.e. `D1: 3*x4...` vs `c3: 4 x4...`. Seems inconsistent so might be the source of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lp file has constants on the left-hand-side, which gurobi are interpreting as variables.

```
 >>> m.read("sample.lp")
    Read LP format model from file sample.lp
Reading time = 0.00 seconds
: 5 rows, 10 columns, 16 nonzeros

>>> m.getVars()                                                                                                                                                                                                          
[<gurobi.Var x1>,
 <gurobi.Var x2>,
 <gurobi.Var x3>,
 <gurobi.Var x4>,
 <gurobi.Var x5>,
 <gurobi.Var 28>,
 <gurobi.Var 14>,
 <gurobi.Var 22>,
 <gurobi.Var 2>,
 <gurobi.Var 1>]
```

To fix, move the constants to the right.

```
    Maximize
 x1 +  x2 +  x3 + 1 x4 + 1 x5

Subject To
c1: 3 x1 + 5 x2 + 2 x3 + 5 x4 + 7 x5 <= 28
c2: 2 x1 + 0 x2 + 0 x3 + 8 x4 <= 14
c3: 4 x4 + 5 x5 <= 22
c4: 3 x2 <= 2
D1: 3 x4 >= 1

Bounds
x1 <= 1
x2 <= 1
x3 <= 1
x4 <= 1
x5 <= 1

Integers
x1 x2 x3 x4 x5
End
```

This will give the intended answer.

```
>>> m.read("sample.lp")
        Read LP format model from file sample.lp
    Reading time = 0.00 seconds
    : 5 rows, 5 columns, 11 nonzeros
>>> m.optimize()
   Optimal solution found (tolerance 1.00e-04)
   Best objective 4.000000000000e+00, best bound 4.000000000000e+00, gap 0.0000%

>>> m.getVars()
   [<gurobi.Var x1 (value 1.0)>,
 <gurobi.Var x2 (value 0.0)>,
 <gurobi.Var x3 (value 1.0)>,
 <gurobi.Var x4 (value 1.0)>,
 <gurobi.Var x5 (value 1.0)>]
```